# Unable to edit a post's tags properly [React JS] due to an uncaught type error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern

new to React and was following along with a tutorial online

I ran into an issue when editing a post, namely, I could edit all the other fields like "title", "creator", "message", but the site wouldn't load when I updated the tag--I'd have to manually refresh the page to see any changes.

Here's the issue-causing code that I had originally:

```
<Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary">{post.tags.map((tag) => `#${tag} `)}</Typography>
```

As you can see, I wanted to enter something like "tag1, tag2, tag3" in the tags field and have it displayed on the post as "#tag1 #tag2 #tag3". However, my console said that post.tags.map is not a function. However, this was used successfully in the tutorial, does this function no longer work?

When I refresh the page, the tags are successfully updated. However, before refreshing, all the components of the page aside from the background css vanishes.

For the sake of just getting the edit function to work, I changed it to:

```
<Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary">{post.tags}</Typography>
```

Which works, but just displays the tags as "tag1 tag2 tag3" without the hashtags.
Again, this is not a big deal, but I am confused as to why post.tags.map did not work. Again, I am new to JS so I might have done something silly.

Here is the code for the postMessage model:

```
const postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    message: String,
    creator: String,
    tags: [String],
    selectedFile: String,
    likeCount: {
    type: Number, 
    default: 0
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: new Date()
    }
});
```

On top of asking why post.tags.map does not work, how would I get each tag to be displayed with a hashtag before it without having to manually type the hashtag in the field? Currently, with my temporary "fix", all the commas also are displayed on the post, which I assume is because it's putting all the tags as a single string element of the array.

*Some additional information that might be helpful:*

The site only acts strange when **editing** a post's tags, not when creating a post with tags. This makes me wonder if there's some funny business with any updatePost functions--however, if that were the case, that would mean I wouldn't be able to update any of the other fields either, which I can.

Here's my code for the Form:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { TextField, Button, Typography, Paper } from '@material-ui/core';
import FileBase from 'react-file-base64';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';


import useStyles from './styles';
import { createPost, updatePost } from '../../actions/posts';

// get current ID

const Form = ({ currentId, setCurrentId }) => {
    const [postData, setPostData] = useState({
        creator: '', title: '', message: '', tags: '', selectedFile: ''
    });

    const post = useSelector((state) => currentId ? state.posts.find((p) => p._id === currentId) : null);
    const classes = useStyles();
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(() => {
        if(post) setPostData(post);
    }, [post]);

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        if(currentId) {
            dispatch(updatePost(currentId, postData));
        } else {
            dispatch(createPost(postData));
        }
        clear();
    }

    const clear = () => {
        setCurrentId(null);
        setPostData({creator: '', title: '', message: '', tags: '', selectedFile: ''});
    }

    return (
        <Paper className={classes.paper}>
            <form autoComplete='off' noValidate className={`${classes.root} ${classes.form}`} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <Typography variant="h6">{ currentId ? 'Editing' : 'Creating' } a Post </Typography>
                <TextField name="creator" variant="outlined" label="Creator" fullWidth value={postData.creator} onChange={(e) => setPostData({ ...postData, creator: e.target.value })} />
                <TextField name="title" variant="outlined" label="Title" fullWidth value={postData.title} onChange={(e) => setPostData({ ...postData, title: e.target.value })} />
                <TextField name="message" variant="outlined" label="Message" fullWidth value={postData.message} onChange={(e) => setPostData({ ...postData, message: e.target.value })} />
                <TextField name="tags" variant="outlined" label="Tags" fullWidth value={postData.tags} onChange={(e) => setPostData({ ...postData, tags: e.target.value })} />
                <div className={classes.fileInput}>
                    <FileBase type="file" multiple={false} onDone={({base64}) => setPostData({ ...postData, selectedFile: base64})}/>
                </div>
                <Button className={classes.buttonSubmit} variant="contained" color="primary" size="large" type="submit" fullWidth>Submit</Button>
                <Button variant="contained" color="secondary" size="small" onClick={clear} fullWidth>Clear</Button>
            </form>
        </Paper>
    );
}

export default Form;
```

And, just to be thorough, my code in actions/posts.js:

```
export const updatePost = (id, post) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        const { data } = await api.updatePost(id, post);

        dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE', payload: data });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

If there is any other bits of code you'd need to see, let me know and I'll update this post.
Thanks

Comment: Can you try including a check, by changing post.tags.map => post?.tags?.map

Comment: Tried it and got this: Uncaught TypeError: _post$tags.map is not a function. Same issue as before, however refreshing the page has the post successfully updated, as before.

Comment: I can see that tags is of type string  =>  tags: '' to tags.map will throw an error,  checking all the places where you set it,  and include checks while you debug Array.isArray(post?.tags) ? post?.tags.map( ) : null